Is Cloudfront distribution backed by s3 able to return entire "folder" via prefix?
I am trying query cloudfront with key prefix. ex. of key "{uuid}/static/{uuid}.json".
When trying to query with request, it will return the correct file.
res = requests.get("https://example.cloudfront.net/{uuid}/static/{uuid}.json")

I tried to get the entire folder with under "{uuid}/static/", I receive a key not found error.
res = requests.get("https://example.cloudfront.net/?prefix={uuid}/static/")

The bucket has "Action": "s3:*" permission for testing purpose.
I followed the instruction on instruction below but it does not work.
Cloudfront backed S3 bucket: listing bucket contents over https with prefix
I am trying to mimic listObjectsV2 the function
Anyone have any idea?

Are you trying with the correct {uuid} out of the 2 mentioned?

It is correct.  I copied the key from S3 and remove the last portion of it.

Does CloudFront point to a Static Website endpoint for the bucket? It would look something like http://bucket-name.s3-website.Region.amazonaws.com. It is the Static Website service that provides that bucket listing. You can get the same result if you point to the Static Website URL without using CloudFront.
